# ¿Como obtener datos de una Api?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando obtener los datos de la siguiente API: https://xkcd.com/json.html ,lo estoy haciendo por medio de fetch pero no lo estoy logrando con HTML, CSS, y JavaScript puro.

```
(async function load (){

    async function getData(url) {
       fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log('data:', data))
        .catch(()=> console.log('algo fallo'))
    }

const info = await getData ('https://xkcd.com/info.0.json');
})();
```

Esta es la otra forma en la que lo estoy haciendo

```
(async function load (){

   async function getData(url) {
     const response = await fetch(url);
     const data = await response.json();
     return data
   }

const info = await getData ('https://xkcd.com/info.0.json');

console.log(info)
})();
```

Por favor necesito sus ayudas URGENTEMENTE, gracias.

Comment: Al parecer es un problema con la API o enpoint,  **no responde** Tal vez te interese buscar sobre como crear una **REST API**

Comment: Hola NikolaTesla, la cuestión es que cuando la voy a consultar en Postman, si me arroja el contenido de la API, pero cuando le hago el fetch no me deja intentarlo.

Comment: La API tiene problemas de CORS por eso no se puede consultar desde el navegador. El código está bien, puedes probarlo con otra api: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

Comment: No me ha dado problemas ejecutar tu código ¿que error específico te está dando? porque solo has dicho que no lo estás logrando, pero no el por qué. Probe a través de la consola de SO y me dio un problema de CORS, no se si será lo mismo para tí

Comment: Ahh, ya habían comentado lo mismo... bueno, eso

Answer (score 0):

```js
(async function load (){

   async function getData(url) {
     let c = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
     const response = await fetch(c+url);
     const data = await response.json();
     return data
   }

const info = await getData ('https://xkcd.com/info.0.json');

console.log(info)
})();
```

No he indagado a profundidad la documentación de https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/
Pero cuando lo pones antes de la url de tu json a extraer los datos hace que funcione :D!
Yo también estuve indagando este problema, creo que es un tema de la configuración de las API y el endpoint.
Espero que te pueda ser util y si derrepente encuentras otro método, lo compartas.
¡Saludos!

Comment: Gracias Alex. OK

Answer (score 0):

Parece que es un problema de cors. Eso creo que tiene que ver con los headers que usas en fetch. Tienes que investigar más sobre la API a ver que headers usa. Mira lo que me sale cuando lo pongo en la consola: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]